# Symfony2 Charset for queries parameters

Tags: symfony, configuration, character-encoding, query-builder

I have a project in Symfony2 which works good at my localhost, but after moving it to external server problem has started.

1. I don't see any results names from database which contains polish characters
2. In Profiler i checked queries:

   - 'Parameters' section has correct charset
   - 'runnable query' has the same parameters but with bad charset

for example:

`(...) 
WHERE ((((c1_.name LIKE '%Å�%') OR (c3_.name LIKE '%Å�%') OR (..)`
`Parameters: ['%ś%', '%ś%', (...)]`

All  database tables has charset = utf8_unicode_ci.

In config.yml i set

```
doctrine: 
    dbal: 
      charset: UTF8
```

Setting framework charset doesn't work.

/config.php test says:

```
RECOMMENDATIONS:
  1. Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended).
  2. Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.
  3. Set magic_quotes_gpc to off in php.ini*.
  * Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "/usr/local/php/php.ini".
```

But unfortunatelly i have no access to php.ini on that server. Is that possible magic_quotes_gpc caused that problem?
I don't have access to command line too, so i have added project (database, file system, vendors) via  ftp, and phpmyadmin.

Becouse I don't have problem on my localhost i guess that is problem with server configuration, and I have no access to that, the only way I see is to try to change charset configuration of QueryBuilder. Where can I do that? Do you know what else could cause that problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you compared phpinfo(); on both servers? Else, is your external web server running utf-8? (AddDefaultCharset UTF-8, php_value default_charset "UTF-8" inside htaccess)

Comment: I've set charsets UTF8 as you said, and compared phpinfos fields with charsets. They are the same but problem is still there. I read that this server is running by default latin2, so i've tried to change everything to latin2 but that didn't help. I'm trying to find place/function which replace '?' signs with elements from parameters array. Is that PDOStatment job? How can I check what is going on there step by step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found solution:
To set "SET NAMES utf8" I changed my doctrine config

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
          driver:   %database_driver%
          host:     %database_host%
          port:     %database_port%
          dbname:   %database_name%
          user:     %database_user%
          password: %database_password%
          charset:  UTF8
          options:
             1002:  "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

It works fine now.